# django cutom image name on upload

Tags: django, image-uploading

I need create a image upload with django, the problem is, django always saving in a global project(called linkdump) folder, I want save it on the project folder(linktracker).

setting.py:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

model:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    link_description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link_image = models.ImageField(upload_to= './static/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.link_description

    class Admin:
        pass
```

now in the view:

```
<img src="{% static link.link_image %}" alt="{{ link.link_description }}">
```

it returns

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/static/o-BLUE-LIGHT-SLEEP-facebook.jpg
```

and the upload is in the project folder(linkdump), not inside the app.

Comment: Try to set `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a function to return a custom path for the ImageField:

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return 'your/custom/path/here'

class Link(models.Model):
    . . .
    link_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

Now you can use information from the model instance to build up the path to upload to.

Additionally, you don't want to use the {% static %} template tag to specify the path to the image. You would just use the `.url` property of the field:

```
<img src="{{ link.link_image.url }}" alt="{{ link.link_description }}" />
```